# Throwing a custom exception instead of other types of exceptions

Tags: java, http, exception

I have a program in which I want to throw one of 4 exceptions that I define.
I get an HTTP response and according its error code I want to throw the exceptions:

Here is an example:

```
public List<Map<String, Object>> getData(String product) {
    
    try {
        Response<DataGeneralResponse> response = dataApi.dataGet(product).execute();
        if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
            log.error(String.format("Failed to get data for product [%s] error [%s]",
                    product,
                    Util.getErrorMsg(response)));
        }
        DataGeneralResponse body = response.body();
        return body != null ? body.getData(): null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
                        log.error(String.format("Failed to get data for product [%s] error[%s]",
                    product,
                    Util.getErrorMsg(response)));
    }
    return null;
}
```

So I need to to something like that in Util:

```
public void handleResponse(Response<DataGeneralResponse> response) throws CustomException {
    switch (response.code()) {
        case 500: throw new FirstCustomException(");
        break;
        case 404: throw new SecondCustomException(");
        break;
        default: throw new UnknownCustomException(");
    }
}
```

But when I try to remove the catch clause I get unhandled IOException error on the execute method and on the getErrorMsg method.

Can someone help please?

Answer (score 2):

> I get unhandled IOException error on the execute method and on the getErrorMsg method.

This indicates that you have a method, which is trying to throw a [checked exception](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/04/java-checked-unchecked-exceptions-with-examples/#:%7E:text=The%20main%20difference%20between%20checked,exceptions%20are%20checked%20at%20runtime.), which is not surrounded by a try catch clause. By Java language standard all methods, which throw checked exceptions must do one of the two ..

- Be surrounded by a `try-catch` block which catches the relevant exception
- Declare that they throw the relevant exception by using the [throws](https://rollbar.com/blog/how-to-use-the-throws-keyword-in-java-and-when-to-use-throw/) keyword

You can use one of the methods above to deal with error you are getting.
If this does not completely solve your problem, please add a comment below and I'll respond.

Comment: @mathkid If this answer has solved your problem please feel free to mark it as accepted.